# Custom CSS, CANNOT LINE UP THE IMAGE SCROLLER

Tags: css, image, wordpress, scroll

http://www.shaunhillphotography.co.uk/

I have an image scroller on my front page and I want it to span the width of the white space. I had it working earlier but accidentally removed the code when I was tweaking the customer CSS.

It looks like it relates to:
    #riva-slider{
    }

I don't know what I need to put in to get the positioning correct.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try increasing the width of the shell and using margin-left to push it to the edge of whitespace.

```
#riva-slider-1-shell {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your CSS file:

```
#riva-slider-1-shell {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This centres the slider, which is a step in the right direction. How do I get rid of the white space specifically for the image scroller so that it is 960px (as wide as the left to right white space).

Comment: Try this instead the previous one: `#riva-slider-1-shell {
    margin-left: -25px;
    width: 960px;
}`